# Percent Metric in Kibana 4?

Tags: metrics, kibana-4, elastic-stack

Hey I'm using the elk stack to store and view test results. I want to see a nice display something like this:

_**Pass**_____**Fail**_

99.99%___00.01%

However I can't find any way to do this. Is this possible in Kibana 4? I feel like this is a very basic feature that should be available...

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly display the count of pass/fail in a table.  Displaying the percents isn't possible in Kibana 4.0 or 4.1

If you need a visualization of the percentages, you can use a pie chart or a bar chart in percentage mode.

Comment: Any progress on that with 4.5 now? I need to show percentage distribution of terms field changing over time.